# How do I run JavaScript code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

How do I run JavaScript code in Visual Studio Code? I want to run `console.log('Hello, World!);`, but I don't know how. Do I need to install an extension?

Comment: What kind of environment are you trying to run it in? Is it browser-based or node?

Comment: Maybe Node, I'm not using a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install node.js first.
Then run the terminal in vscode with the command: `node namefile`

Answer (score 0):

You can see the `log` in the browser just press `F12` in the browser and select console you will be able the see `log` details there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vscode extension *Code Runner*
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to install NodeJS. You can install it from here: https://nodejs.org/en/
2. Create a new folder and open it in VS Code. then write the javascript code and name it with extension .js   After completing the code save the changes that you made
3. Open the terminal in VS Code. and make sure you are in your project folder (cd yourproject)
4. finally run this command: node yourjsfilename